# .Net resx file: access resource dynamically in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, resx

I know how to access a resource in Razor:

```
@Resources.text.Description
```

But how can I do that, in a loop, and reference the resource name dynamically?
Something like:

```
@foreach (Data.Local in @Model.Locals)
{
    <div>@Resources.text[@local.Name]</div>
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found some trick. In the class Data.Local, the field Name actually is :

```
 string resx = "Resources.text";
 ResourceGetter.GetResourceFrom(resx, name);
```

With name being the resource you want.